# signature byte range is invalid after enabling LTV

Tags: java, itext, amazon-cloudhsm

I am using aws cloudHSM and itext7 to sign the pdf. Everything is fine till i am not enabling LTV.

But after enabling LTV getting error "Atleast one signature has problem" and showing reason signature byte range is invalid.

Below is the code

```
private void ltvEnable(PdfSigner signer, OutputStream baos, String name11,
        OcspClientBouncyCastle ocspClient, CrlClientOnline crlClient, CustomTSAClient tsc) {
    ByteArrayInputStream signedPdfInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream)baos).toByteArray());
    try {
        
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(signedPdfInput);
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(pdfReader.setUnethicalReading(true), new PdfWriter(baos),
                new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
        LtvVerification ltvVerification = new LtvVerification(document);
        SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(document);
        List<String> names = signatureUtil.getSignatureNames();
        String sigName = names.get(names.size() - 1);
        PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = signatureUtil.readSignatureData(sigName);
        if (pkcs7.isTsp()) { 
            ltvVerification.addVerification(sigName, ocspClient, crlClient, LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
                    LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL, LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.YES);
        } else {
            for (String name : names) {
                ltvVerification.addVerification(name, ocspClient, crlClient, LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
                        LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL, LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.YES);
            }
        }
        
        ltvVerification.merge();
        //signer.timestamp(tsc, null);
        document.close();
        pdfReader.close();

    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
        logger.error("Error while making signature ltv enabled");
    }
}
```

Before enabling ltv -:

[image]

After -:

[image]

Comment: How do you enable LTV? Please share the pivotal code.

Comment: Thanks @mkl ... i updated my question with code .

Comment: Hhmmm, ok, could you additionally provide example files, one before and one after applying LTV? At first glance the code looks correct. The only interesting detail is that you use `setUnethicalReading(true)` which might indicate that encryption is involved, and I have not tested LTV enabling of encrypted documents yet.

Comment: If you indeed work with encrypted files, you should also try activating `StampingProperties.preserveEncryption()`.

Comment: Thanks @mkl , i tried with StampingProperties.preserveEncryption() but unfortunately did not get success.

Comment: Could you additionally provide example files, one before and one after applying LTV?

Comment: Sure, can you please provide me your email id.... Actually file has some company information that i can not disclose to all

Comment: You can find an email address in the description of my stack overflow profile.

Comment: Please check your inbox....Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, Looking at the file one issue becomes clear quickly: You don't clear the `baos` before using it again as target of a `PdfWriter`. Thus, your *after* file actually contains two PDFs, the original one and the one with LTV information. Unfortunately there still is an issue thereafter; I'll look into that this at the start of next week.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, i got the issue , now its working fine ....really appreciate your help

Comment: Great. Shall i make my comment an actual answer you can accept or do you want to answer yourself?

Comment: Yes, you can make ....your previous comment was the actual problem in my code ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your architecture you have a `ByteArrayOutputStream` parameter in which you retrieve the pdf to LTV-enable and in which you also in the end return the LTV-enabled result pdf.

In such an architecture have to clear the `ByteArrayOutputStream` between retrieving the original content from it and adding the new content to it.

In your case, therefore, you have to clear it between

```java
ByteArrayInputStream signedPdfInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream)baos).toByteArray());
```

and

```java
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(pdfReader.setUnethicalReading(true), new PdfWriter(baos),
                new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
```